# Как правильно записать в файл данные из EditText Android приложения на SD-карту

Tags: android

Приветствую. Как правильно записать в файл "test.txt" данные из EditText Android приложения на SD-карту? В моем случае вываливается ошибка о прекращении процесса программы.

```
public void mNoteSaveClick(View v) {
    saveFile(FILEPATH + nnTitleText.getText().toString() + FILEEXT);
}

private void saveFile(String FileName) {
    boolean yoba;
    if (yoba = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        try {
            OutputStream outStream = openFileOutput(FileName, 0);
            OutputStreamWriter sw = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
            sw.write(nnTitleText.getText().toString());
            sw.write(nnNoteText.getText().toString());
            sw.close();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception111",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Про кодировку не забудьте, а то вы пишите в дефолтной. Ну и конечно, по традиции, стримы принято закрывать после использования в любом случае, а не только в случаи успешной записи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первым делом Вам надо убедиться, что в манифесте приложения выставлены требуемые права на запись на SD-карту, а именно [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.app.myapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

После этого стандартная запись должна работать

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream ("/sdcard/filename");
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    os.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
} finally {
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: Данные я записал в файл, только каждый раз файл перезаписывается новыми данными... а как сделать чтоб в файл Дописывались данные?

Comment: Используйте конструктор с параметром append: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29

Comment: Огромное спасибо! И наверно последний вопрос по данной теме. Как можно дописать данные в файл через FileOutputStream(Filename,true), только так чтоб строка предшествующая записи удалялась и вместо нее записывалась следующая? Наверно для таких целей FileOutputStream не предназначен, да и я пытаюсь создать XML-файл